# Get pandas nth entry after resampling ( on 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, resampling

I have such a dataframe df:

```
            Data
Date    
2013-01-01  1
2013-01-01  3
2013-01-01  0
2013-02-01  4
2013-02-01  0
```

It continues with other succeeding dates by month and values.
I want to get nth element for each group of a month in a separate subset.

I thought of re-sampling using month and getting `nth` element like we can get `mean, min, max`...

nth element is in range 0 to min

where

```
min_to_keep = int(df.resample('M').count().min()[0])
```

Except that `pandas#nth` method is not there for me, it's for `Group` object but not `Resampler`.

Wanted result is like:

```
1  2013-01-01  1
   2013-02-01  4

2  2013-01-01  3
   2013-02-01  0

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group and then form the separate `DataFrames` using `.nth`

```
import pandas as pd

gp = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
l = [gp.nth(i) for i in range(gp.size().max())]

# If need a DataFrame
pd.concat(l, keys=list(range(gp.size().max())))
              Data
  Date            
0 2013-01-31     1
  2013-02-28     4
1 2013-01-31     3
  2013-02-28     0
2 2013-01-31     0
```